# Using Google Hangouts in Chrome browser to make calls with Google Fi number- have no call history?

Tags: google-chrome, google-hangouts, google-fi

Lost my phone, using hangouts via my browser (chrome). I open it via the app launcher thing:
[image]

So I guess google hangouts has no way of listing my call history!? I can't seem to find a list of calls I have made sorted from newest to latest- like every cell phone interface has.

These are my options in the UI:

[image]

I click conversations and I have a list of SMS messages I have sent- these are sorted by most recent which is what I would expect. Its only sms messages though not phone calls.

When I click "phone calls" I see a list of ALL my contacts sort alphabetically- wtf this is useless. I cannot find a list of my recent *calls*. This is infuriating.

For example, A delivery guy called me, we spoke about the order, I went to go call him back and could not because I have no call history and obviously the number isn't in my contacts.

EDIT: this is what I see when clicking "+ New Conversation" under phone calls tab
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] the question to mention that you have a Google Fi phone number.

Comment: This question was bumped by Community user 9 times. I’m voting to close this question because Google Hangouts was retired.

Answer (score 0):

For Google Fi users:

From [See your call and text history](https://support.google.com/fi/answer/6380147?hl=en)

> See your call and text history
> Your call and text history is a detailed list of every call and text you've made and received across all your Google Fi devices. You can see your history only on the Google Fi website, not in the app.
>
> To see your call and text history:
>
> 1. Open the Google Fi website.
> 2. In the Account tab, go to "Settings."
> 3. Click History.

---

For non-Google Fi users:

From [Make a phone call with classic Hangouts](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3187125?hl=en)

> Access your call history
>
> 1. On your computer, go to Hangouts at hangouts.google.com or in Gmail.
> 2. Click the Phone tab .
> 3. Click New conversation and then Add credit .
> 4. Your calling credits, call, and billing history will show up in Google Voice.
>    You can also use Google Voice Takeout to download your call history.

[image]

The *Add credit* button points to https://voice.google.com/u/0/billing?hl=en

Comment: I dont see "Add credit". I click "Phone calls" and then I see a list of my contacts and a "+ Conversation" at the top. If I click that + button I just have the option to enter a phone number

Comment: Do you have only one Google account? If not, have you reviewed all your Google accounts?

Comment: i have only one account i use with google fi

Comment: Added a screenshot

Comment: adding my own screenshot to my post, I dont know what "credit" is. I use google fi, dont need to use credits